# Problema con crystal reports

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, crystal-reports

Hice una aplicacion que incluye CrystalReports y funciona bien, el problema viene cuando creo el ejecutable y lo instalo en otra computadora, la aplicacion se instala y todo pero cuando le doy click al boton que funciona como visualizador de mis reportes aparece este error:

> Se produjo una excepción en el inicializador de tipo de
>   'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument'

Utilice visual studio 2017 y cr for visual studio

Comment: Si está instalando en una máquina de 64 bits, asegúrese de que las propiedades de la aplicación tenga seleccionado  **"Cualquier CPU"** como objetivo de la plataforma, y ​​desmarque la casilla de verificación "Preferir 32 bits" si tiene la opción. Crystal es muy delicado con los ensamblados de 32/64 bits, y hace algunas suposiciones bastante contra intuitivas que son muy difíciles de solucionar.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez por favor publícalo como respuesta. Esta puede ser es una solución.

Comment: @J.Rodríguez La pc destino es de 64 bits e instale el runtime de 64 bits, desmarque la opcion de preferir 32 bits, y aun así me sale el error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya pude resolver mi problema, solo tuve que instalar

> **CRRuntime_64bit_13_0_22**

Supongo que para los que tienen el mismo error se soluciona de la misma manera.

Comment: es lo que te respondi en el punto dos.

Answer (score 0):

Cuando utilizan `CrystalReports` para hacer sus proyectos no olviden que este es de **paga**, por lo cual debes de comprar la licencia, ademas de tener versiones para **desarrollo y otro cliente**, ademas de tener versiones de **x86 y x64**.

Pero bueno, el problema puede estar en:

> **1.-** No agregaste el instalador de **CrystalReports** en el instalador de tu aplicacion.
>   **2.-** No estas instalando la version correcta de **CrystalReports**, esto en el sentido de que si es de x86 o x64.
>   **3.-** No estas instalando la **versión cliente**, ya que la versión desarrollador requiere necesariamente que los componentes de `Visual Studio` esten instaladas localmente.

La solucion es simple.

1. Agrega el instalador `CrystalReports` en su versión correcta que sea el de cliente, dentro del instalador de tu sistema(que es lo que hacen muchos).
2. Instala `CrystalReports` en su version correcta por separado, es decir antes o después de instalar tu sistema, pero ten en cuenta que deberas colocarlo como requisito para tu sistema.
3. Utiliza/agrega los `dll` de `CrystalReports` client como referencia en tu proyecto al momento de desarrollo, con lo cual evitaras los anteriores pasos.

Comment: por lo que he leido, necesito tener la misma version (64 o 32 bits) he verificado esto y son las mismas versiones, tambien he leido acerca de cambiar el archivo app.config de mi proyecto pero la verdad es que no entiendo muy bien eso, voy a tratar con una instalacion limpia, descargue 2 arcchivos diferentes a ver si sirven (CRRuntime_64bit y CRforVS_redist_install_64bit ambos en la version 13.0.22), sino la unica solucion factible para no romperme la cabeza es installar vs en la otra pc jaja

Answer (score 0):

Exactamente fue el error de compilar con crystal reports de 32 bits;
en las propiedades del proyecto (en mi caso vs2019) deshabilitar "preferir 32 bits" y en el combobox de plataforma del destino escoger 64 bits.

Después en "Rutas de acceso de la referencia", esta Crystal reports pero con 32 bits; se debe de agregar y dejar solamente:

C:\Program Files (x86)\SAP BusinessObjects\Crystal Reports for .NET Framework 4.0\Common\SAP BusinessObjects Enterprise XI 4.0\win64_x64\dotnet\

ya que esta la ruta de 32 bits.

Se compila la aplicación y se vuenve regenrar el instalador.

Tambien hay que instalar en la máuina destino el runtime de 64 bits de la versión que se esta utilizando de crystal reports y LISTO.... YA NO MARCA ERROR Y MUESTRA EL REPORTE SIN PROBLEMAS